# Could not invoke RNFirebaseFirestore.collectionOnSnapshot null Failed

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-android

I have below config
**app/build.gradle**

```
 implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.+"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.+"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.+"
    implementation(project(':react-native-maps')) {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-contacts')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

**Package.json**

```
"react": "16.6.3",
    "react-native": "0.58.6",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-contacts": "^3.1.4",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.2.3",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-mauron85-background-geolocation": "^0.5.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^1.1.1",
    "react-navigation": "^3.3.2"
```

**Android/gradle**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.1'
```

When I try to follow

https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available-libraries

**getting error here**

```
this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('locations').onSnapshot(this.getCollectionData)
```

[image]

App getting crashed

Please help

Thanks

Comment: what did you refer for firebase integration??

Comment: rnfirebase library

Comment: I am able to add data in firebase, but its throwing error on using onSnapshot

Comment: did you follow this documentation [rn-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/installation/initial-setup#Creating-a-new-project) ??

Comment: yes getting error here this.unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().collection('locations').onSnapshot(this.getCollectionData

Comment: send a screenshot of the errorscreen

Comment: updated screenshot

Comment: Could you try this code `firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("locations")
      .get()
      .then(QuerySnapshot => {
        console.log( QuerySnapshot._docs.length);
      });`

Comment: same issue occuring

Comment: did you add google-services.json in android/app/ folder??

Comment: Yes I did, I am able to add data, but unable to get , when I did "firebase.firestore().collection('locations').doc('test').set({ test: 'test' })" it is able to add data data in firestore

Comment: add documents like this `firebase.firestore().collection('locations').add({ test: 'test' })` and check.

Comment: There is not issue with add or set,,, the issue is with fetch only

Comment: there could be problem with document creating. Just give a try with the abov code for both adding and retrival

Comment: I tried still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I have got same error. Please create the collection with the name 'locations' and add a dummy document. Then try.